Возможно ли в Bitrix получить значения пользовательского поля enumeration?
У меня есть поле в Bitrix (enumeration). 
Я получаю данные в таком же виде, то есть "1 - 444", например, но Bitrix ожидает значение ID поля, а не строки. Поле сделки UF_CRM_..., которое как раз является списком (enumeration), возвращает значение 45 для "1 - 444" поля и 47 для поля "2 - 666". Как я по значению "1 - 444" могу получить его ID, чтобы передать в поле UF_CRM_... при создании новой сделки?
Пример тестовый, на самом деле значений по типу "1 - 444" больше и они периодически меняются. Каким методом можно получить ID по VALUE?
Использую python библиотеку fasr_bitrix24, либо же сам REST API, есть ли там такой метод?

Проблема XY — Википедия. Если Вам нужен алгоритм преобразования, то нужны реальные (не тестовые) данные (и это возможно только при условии, что преобразование в принципе имеет место (т.е. значение не является маской ID)).  Поищите исполнителя на фрилансе...

Преобразование необходимо при запуске кода, который стационарно работает и обращается к Bitrix. Данные могут изменяться, потому разницы тестовые данные или реальные нет, так как они все равно могут измениться во время работы кода

В таком случае, что Вам позволяет думать, что данные имеют вычисляемую связь с ID?

Вопрос как раз в том, возможно ли это или нет. Решение может быть простым, но в API я не нашла нужного метода. Я знаю только то, что запрос сделки возращает в этом поле ID, а не само текстовое значение. Раз такое происходит, то скорее всего внутри битрикса связь есть, но не факт, что оно реализовано в API

Я немного разочарована, думала что это интересная задачка... Удалите из вопроса эти строки: , возвращает значение 45 для "1 - 444" поля и 47 для поля "2 - 666", Пример тестовый, на самом деле значений по типу "1 - 444" больше и они периодически меняются. .


Получите список значений для поля:
Используйте метод  crm.deal.fields
(Возвращает описание полей сделки - json <=> dict)

from fast_bitrix24 import Bitrix

# Ваш код ^^^^^^^

# Получите поля сделки
fields = bx.call('crm.deal.fields')

# Найдите ваше пользовательское поле
enum_field = fields['UF_CRM_YOUR_FIELD']  # Замените на ваше поле

# Создайте соответствие значений и ID
value_to_id = {item['VALUE']: item['ID'] for item in enum_field['items']}

# Пример значения, для которого нужно получить ID
value = "1 - 444"
id_value = value_to_id.get(value)

if id_value is not None:
    print(f"ID для '{value}': {id_value}")
else:
    print(f"Значение '{value}' не найдено.")


Если используете REST API напрямую, вы можете выполнить аналогичные шаги,
отправив запрос к методу  crm.deal.fields
URL для запроса будет выглядеть следующим образом:

https://your_bitrix24_domain/rest/crm.deal.fields.json?auth=your_access_token

Так Вы сможете динамически получать ID по значениям, которые могут меняться.
